# Not able to create file on runtime in linux using java code

Tags: linux, java-io, apache-storm

I am compiling maven project for running Storm Topology on linux machine.

Following is a method in a Bolt Class,here I want to create a file on runtime where buffered Reader will collect the data from input and will write it into a file.

**Tuple input object** : contains the data to be written.
**/root/data/javacode/top_output.csv** : file name.
All IO packages are imported in the code already.

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    String sentence = input.getString(0);
    String[] process = sentence.split(" ");
    File file = new File("/root/data/jcode/top_output.csv");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());  // line no. 36
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);  
    for (String proc : process) {
        proc = proc.trim();
        if (!proc.isEmpty()) {
            collector.emit(new Values(proc));
            bw.write(proc);    // line no. 42
        }
    }
    bw.close();
}
```

Whenever I compile the project using **mvn package**,it gives compilation error :

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ lgassStorm ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /root/data/lgassStorm/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /root/data/lgassStorm/src/main/java/lgaas/bolts/DataNormalizer.java:[36,19] error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
[ERROR] /root/data/lgassStorm/src/main/java/lgaas/bolts/DataNormalizer.java:[42,13] error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
[INFO] 2 errors
```

Whenever I comment Filewriter related code, it works successfully. Line number are mentioned above in code.
What's wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the function execute throws an IOException.

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) throws IOException {
```

or you can catch the exception. This is in case one of the IO operations fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try to throws an IOException or surround your code to TryCatch Block.

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector){
try{
your code...
}catch (IOException e){
e.printStackTrace ();
}
}
```

Comment: I tried that too but when file doesn't exist of file system, code gives compilation error and if file already exists, it is compiled successfully.